# Facebook not detecting og tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

Once again I find myself in need of your collective genius. I have a website built in ASP.NET 4.5 using c#, its a web forms site if that is at all relevant.
I have the following script in my master page to generate the required meta og:whatever tags.

```
var ogtitle = "<meta name=\"og:title\" content=\"" + this.Page.Title + "\" />";
        var ogsname = "<meta name=\"og:site_name\" content=\"Griffiths Web Design\" />";
        var ogtype = "<meta name=\"og:type\" content=\"website\" />";
        var ogdesc = "<meta name=\"og:description\" content=\"" + this.Page.MetaDescription + "\" />";
        var ogurl = "<meta name=\"og:url\" content=\"" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath + "\" />";
        var ogimg = "<meta name=\"og:image\" content=\"www.griffithswebdesign.com/images/binaryearth.jpg\" />";
        fbmets.Text = ogimg + ogtitle + ogurl + ogsname + ogtype + ogdesc;
```

Which, when I run the site generates the following meta tags (I know they are there because I can see them when I view source)

```
<meta name="og:image" content="www.griffithswebdesign.com/images/binaryearth.jpg" /><meta name="og:title" content="A Simple blogging system in ASP.NET" /><meta name="og:url" content="/Blog/Post/24" /><meta name="og:site_name" content="Griffiths Web Design" /><meta name="og:type" content="website" /><meta name="og:description" content="A Simple blogging system in ASP.NET" />
```

Despite this when I try to share a link from my site to Facebook it comes up as not found. When I use the facebook debugger it is unable to find the tags. Is there something I'm missing? or have I completely misunderstood the process? as far as I can tell I have the required tags present in each page thanks to the script in the master page. Obviously something is wrong but as I said I'm lost.

Although this appears to be happening on every page here is a link to a page so you can have a look:

http://www.griffithswebdesign.com/Blog/Post/24

Any help would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Could you provide the URL for the page

Comment: http://www.griffithswebdesign.com/Blog/Post/24

Comment: @AyushGupta I have added a link. The issue seems to be present on all pages though.

Comment: I cannot open `http://www.griffithswebdesign.com/Blog/Post/24`, I get a 404 (page not found) error.

Comment: really? I can open it from my lapto and my phone

Comment: Wait, by default I am using ipv6. I'll try using ipv4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your website does not work with ipv6, although it has a AAAA record. This is my request when I use ipv6:

```
GET /Blog/Post/24 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.griffithswebdesign.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0 Iceweasel/38.7.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Wed, 13 Apr 2016 13:14:16 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 315
```

When I force ipv4 using wget (`wget -4 -S  http://www.griffithswebdesign.com/Blog/Post/24`), I see this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 63543
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=n324zpflwyicoiwdwy0fynbu; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 13 Apr 2016 13:17:10 GMT
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is this an answer to his question?

Comment: @Hill, the question/problem was that Facebook was not detecting the `og` tags. The OP focuses on the generated HTML. But there can be can be different reasons for this. It seems Facebook is using ipv6 to download the webpage - if available. If the webserver is not properly configured* for ipv6, this will not work. If Facebook cannot download the page, it cannot find the `og` tags. So the problem will be fixed after the ipv6 issue has been fixed, or ipv6 is disabled. * It is also possible that the problem is DNS related. But that is impossible for me to determine. The OP has to check that.

Answer (score 2):

OK here's an issue,

you use `meta name` in the og tags, while the proper syntax is `meta property`, switch the `name` to `property`, then try debugging.

The proper og tags should be

```
<meta property="og:image" content="www.griffithswebdesign.com/images/binaryearth.jpg" />
<meta property="og:title" content="A Simple blogging system in ASP.NET" />
<meta property="og:url" content="/Blog/Post/24" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Griffiths Web Design" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:description" content="A Simple blogging system in ASP.NET" />
```